# Pandas DataFrame remove strings having a certain characters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with a lot of text data. I want to remove all lines starting with "*" mark. Therefore, I tried a small example as the following.

```
string1 = '''* This needs to be gone
But this line should stay
*remove 
* this too
End'''

string2 = '''* This needs to be gone
But this line should stay
*remove 
* this too
End'''

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[string1,string2]})
df['a'] = df['a'].map(lambda a: (re.sub(r'(?m)^\*.*\n?', '', a, flags=re.MULTILINE)))
```

It could perfectly do the job. However, when I applied the same function to my original DataFrame it is not working. Can you help me to identify the issue?

```
df2['NewsText'] = df2['NewsText'].map(lambda a: (re.sub(r'(?m)^\*.*\n?', '', a, flags=re.MULTILINE)))
df2.head()
```

[Pease see the attached image of my original DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Tae.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Given your example data

- `.str.split('\n')` creates a list of each section
- `.apply(lambda x: '\n'.join([y for y in x if '*' not in y]))` uses a list comprehension to remove each sentence with `*` and then joins it back into a string.

  - You can join with `' '.join` or `''.join`
- `.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if '*' not in y])` if you want to have a list instead of a long string.

```py
|    | a                         |
|---:|:--------------------------|
|  0 | * This needs to be gone   |
|    | But this line should stay |
|    | *remove                   |
|    | * this too                |
|    | End                       |
|  1 | * This needs to be gone   |
|    | But this line should stay |
|    | *remove                   |
|    | * this too                |
|    | End                       |

# remove sections with '*'
df['a'] = df['a'].str.split('\n').apply(lambda x: '\n'.join([y for y in x if '*' not in y]))

# final
|    | a                         |
|---:|:--------------------------|
|  0 | But this line should stay |
|    | End                       |
|  1 | But this line should stay |
|    | End                       |
```